# File Operation in Process.java (com.android.os)

Tags: java, android, file-io, operating-system, java-native-interface

I am trying to load a library stored at the location **/sdcard/mycustomlib.so** in **Process.java** file in the **com.android.os** package. 
But it doesn't allow me to do so and throws the following error :

```
..
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library /sdcard/mycustomlib.so not found
..
```

Moreover even if i try to read a a simple text file stored at **/sdcard/custom.txt** in **Process.java**, it doesn't allows me to do so and gives the error :

```
..
FileNotFound open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
..
```

I have checked through the **adb shell** that both the files **mycustomlib.so** and **custom.txt** exists at the path **/sdcard/**.

Comment: Did you check https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/zYgsb6nlN6s

Comment: You cannot load libraries from non-executable storage such as the sdcard.  Also, at least on devices where the sdcard is removable, critical processes are not allowed to access it, since anyone with an open fd to it gets killed when it is removed.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I tried loading the library from /data/xyz_folder also but got the same error.

Comment: Post the exact code you use for the load attempt from the data partition.  Note that your library name is nonstandard.  Post an ls -l of the installed library on the data partition.  How was the library built?